# xml response in pl/sql

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, request, response

```
 with t as( select xmltype('< ROWSET>
 < ROW>
  < DEPTNO>10 < /DEPTNO>
  < NAME>ACCOUNTING< /NAME>
  < LOC>NEW YORK< /LOC>
 < /ROW>
 < ROW>
  < DEPTNO>20< /DEPTNO>
  < DNAME>RESEARCH< /DNAME>
  < LOC>DALLAS< /LOC>
 < /ROW>
 < ROW>
  < DEPTNO>30< /DEPTNO>
  < DNAME>SALES</DNAME>
  < LOC>CHICAGO < /LOC>
 </ROW>
 < ROW>
   < DEPTNO>40< /DEPTNO>
  < DNAME>OPERATIONS< /DNAME>
< LOC>BOSTON< /LOC>
 < /ROW>
< /ROWSET>
 ') x from dual)
select extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DEPTNO') DEPTNO ,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DNAME') DNAME,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/LOC') LOCATION
   from t t, table(xmlsequence(t.x.extract('ROWSET/ROW'))) t2
```

**Result:**

```
DEPTNO  DNAME           LOCATION
10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH             DALLAS
30  SALES            CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

But in my case the XML response is stored in a table in column of xmltype.
In which the same response which is there at the top is present in the xmltype column.
so i used it as follows:

```
with t as( select xml_doc x from xml_table where xml_name='EMPDETAILS' )
select extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DEPTNO') DEPTNO ,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DNAME') DNAME,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/LOC') LOCATION
   from t t, table(xmlsequence(t.x.extract('ROWSET/ROW'))) t2
```

It is not returning any rows. for which the same response is used in both the queries.

Please let me know whether i need to change the way how i am using the second query.

Plz help...thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please format queries and results as code samples - this will prevent people from doing it themselves and just a good manner: unformatted text is very difficult to read

Comment: I have added some formatting for you, but please format it yourself in the future.

Comment: Have you checked that `select count(*) from xml_table where xml_name='EMPDETAILS'` returns > 0?

Comment: In the same example(provided above) , one more tag is present before ROWSET. In this case the above soilution is not working .How can we change the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to duplicate. See code sample below:

Create table

```
create table xml_table (
  xml_name varchar2(100),
  xml_doc  xmltype
);
```

Insert data

```
insert into xml_table (xml_name, xml_doc) values (
  'EMPDETAILS',
xmltype('
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>10 </DEPTNO>
  <NAME>ACCOUNTING</NAME>
  <LOC>NEW YORK</LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>RESEARCH</DNAME>
  <LOC>DALLAS</LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>SALES</DNAME>
  <LOC>CHICAGO</LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>40</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>OPERATIONS</DNAME>
  <LOC>BOSTON</LOC>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
 '));

insert into xml_table (xml_name, xml_doc) values (
  'OTHERDETAILS',
  xmltype('
    <ROWSET>
      <ROW>
        <ELEMENT>HELIUM</ELEMENT>
      </ROW>
    </ROWSET>')
);
```

Query using table data

```
with t as( select xml_doc x from xml_table where xml_name='EMPDETAILS' )
select extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DEPTNO') DEPTNO ,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DNAME') DNAME,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/LOC') LOCATION
   from t t, table(xmlsequence(t.x.extract('ROWSET/ROW'))) t2;
```

Query using XMLType instance

```
with t as( select xmltype('<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>10 </DEPTNO>
  <NAME>ACCOUNTING</NAME>
  <LOC>NEW YORK</LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>20</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>RESEARCH</DNAME>
  <LOC>DALLAS</LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <DEPTNO>30</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>SALES</DNAME>
  <LOC>CHICAGO </LOC>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
   <DEPTNO>40</DEPTNO>
  <DNAME>OPERATIONS</DNAME>
<LOC>BOSTON</LOC>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
 ') x from dual)
select extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DEPTNO') DEPTNO ,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/DNAME') DNAME,
          extractvalue(t2.column_value,'ROW/LOC') LOCATION
   from t t, table(xmlsequence(t.x.extract('ROWSET/ROW'))) t2;
```